# Is there any org.w3c.dom wrapper for JDom?

Tags: java, xml, dom, w3c, jdom

I'm trying to enhance the [jOOX](http://code.google.com/p/joox/) API in a way that it can also operate on [JDom](http://jdom.org) documents, not only `org.w3c.dom.Document`. Instead of duplicating everything, I was wondering if there is any library that implements the interfaces of `org.w3c.dom`, while at the same time wrapping [JDom](http://jdom.org)?

Note, I'm not not looking for `org.jdom.output.DOMOutputter`, which transforms the JDom document into a DOM document. I suspect that frequent transformations would be very slow. I'm looking for a wrapper, which implements w3c dom with JDom classes.

Comment: As usual with standards, there are so many to choose from... :-) You can always define interfaces internal to jOOX that represent XML entities (elements, attributes etc.), and let each such interface have an `org.w3c.dom` implementation and a JDom implementation.

Comment: @EliAcherkan: Yes but that's a lot of work, which I'd like to avoid. After all, there is only one standard, and that's `org.w3c.dom`. So maybe someone already created a wrapper to make JDom adhere to the standard

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd link...](http://xkcd.com/927/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As part of the JDOM 2.x project I have put together exactly that. It is a read-only wrapper for JDOM in a DOM format. It is comprehensive enough to run JDOM through both the native javax.xml.xpath, as well as Xalan XPath engines.... I have used it extensively as part of the JDOM 2.x test harness.

So, if you are using JDOM 2.0.0, you can overlay the JDOM instances by using the DOM code that is in the 'contrib' section.

This is not officially supported JDOM code, but it is probably good enough for your purposes.

See the code at https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/tree/master/contrib/src/java/org/jdom2/contrib/dom

The typical usage is:

```
org.w3c.dom.Document domdoc = org.jdom2.contrib.dom.DOM.wrap(jdomdoc);
```

All the DOM nodes in the returned domdoc also implement the org.jdom2.contrib.dom.Wrapper interface, thus, you can, for example, say:

```
org.jdom2.Element emt = (org.jdom2.Element)((Wrapper)node).getWrapped();
org.jdom2.Document doc = (org.jdom2.Document)((Wrapper)domdoc).getWrapped();
```

This code is *not* officially supported (yet) in the JDOM project.... but it is useful and functional enough.

Comment: Wow, an answer by the _author_ of the wrapper! Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: This looks very nice. Currently, your solution doesn't implement modification of the underlying JDom model. For jOOX, that would be needed, though...